# How to check dxTextBox from child component is empty?

Tags: angular, angular6, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I have a nested component with a dx-text-box.
At a curtain time I want to know at the parent comonent if the text box is empty (value) or not.
How can I check it?
Frank

Answer (score 0):

At the parent component ts I use

```js
@ViewChild(MyChildComponent) myChildComponent: MyChildComponent;
...
if (this.myChildComponent.myValueFromTextBox == '') {...}
```